# Blackberry media query

Tags: css, blackberry

I'm trying to make a version of my website optimize to Blackberry devices, however I lack of information regarding this devices and google seems not to be helping.

Have anyone create website optimize for blackberry before? or know any kind of post or information that could help?

I don't know if media queries could help since those devices seems to open screen standard resolutions.

Comment: It is customary to mark an appropriate answer for a question as being correct (one per question). Please review your questions with answers and, if an appropriate answer exists, click the outlined checkmark next to the answer. :)

Comment: Also, I am interested that you say you searched but didn't seem to find what you are looking for. Have you tried searching Google for [blackberry web optimization](http://www.google.com/search?q=blackberry+web+optimization)?

Comment: http://www.richalot.com/index.cfm/2008/5/27/Tips-For-Optimizing-A-Web-Site-For-BlackBerry-Devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From **[Optimizing A Web Site For BlackBerry Devices](http://www.richalot.com/index.cfm/2008/5/27/Tips-For-Optimizing-A-Web-Site-For-BlackBerry-Devices)**:

> If you thought targeting Web sites to
>   work with several different browsers
>   was difficult enough, try throwing
>   BlackBerry support in the mix.
>   Designing a Web site to work with
>   BlackBerry handheld devices can be
>   frustrating because the BlackBerry Web
>   browser has fewer capabilities than a
>   standard Web browser. This lack of
>   features greatly affects design
>   strategy because slower download
>   speeds and limited screen size must
>   now be factored in.
>
> The first thing you should do when
>   optimizing a site to support
>   BlackBerry devices is download and
>   install the official [BlackBerry
>   Device Simulator](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/downloads/simulators.jsp) and [BlackBerry
>   Email and MDS Services Simulator
>   Package](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/downloads/simulators.jsp). The device simulator and
>   simulator package emulate the
>   functionality of actual BlackBerry
>   products and allow you to access and
>   test a Web site in a virtual
>   environment.
>
> When you first open a site in
>   emulation, you'll probably notice the
>   BlackBerry's CSS support is limited
>   and your site may not look so great.
>   Since most front-end developers are
>   trained to be reactive, your initial
>   solution maybe to attach another
>   stylesheet, target the handheld medium
>   and adjust the classes and ids in that
>   stylesheet accordingly. Unfortunately,
>   the BlackBerry disregards both screen
>   and handheld media style declarations.
>   In fact, many of the useful style
>   declarations that could create a
>   loophole for the lack of media
>   support—including display:none and
>   visiblility:hidden—won't work on a
>   BlackBerry. For a complete list of
>   supported CSS declarations, refer to
>   the [BlackBerry Content Developer
>   Guide](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/8067/645045/8655/8563/1162261/BlackBerry_Browser_4.1_Content_Developer_Guide?nodeid=1162171&vernum=0).
>
> So what's the solution? The real trick
>   to optimizing a Web site for
>   BlackBerry devices (without any hacks
>   or work-arounds) is using well-formed
>   XHTML in conjunction with CSS and
>   omitting unnecessary layout elements
>   using the screen medium. This focus on
>   semantically correct XHTML to drive
>   your layout may not look pretty on the
>   BlackBerry, but it's advantageous for
>   several reasons. For starters, since
>   you're dealing with a limited amount
>   of screen space and relying on what
>   equates to dial-up connection speeds
>   you want to keep the majority of your
>   display content for the BlackBerry as
>   text-based. Secondly, the well-formed
>   code will result in better overall
>   search engine optimization because
>   you're using code standards that are
>   friendlier to the search engine
>   indexing process. Finally, the focus
>   on semantics will make the site
>   scalable and rid you of any worries
>   associated with the consequences of
>   adding text, modifying links or
>   changing the appearance of an element
>   in your stylesheet.
>
> With full-featured browsers integrated
>   into the latest generation of
>   handhelds (Safari on the iPhone, IE in
>   Windows Mobile devices) aesthetics
>   support on mobile devices is vastly
>   improving. Either way, good coding
>   standards promote graceful degradation
>   and a provide a certain level of
>   future proofing that ensures users can
>   view a Web site no matter how outdated
>   or cutting-edge their device is.

Comment: Media queries are supported on most blackberries (OS 4.7 and above) though frustratingly not on the 8520 under emulation (though on a real phone it works...)