# How to increase font size on just blackberries that have small screens with physical keyboards?

Tags: blackberry, css

I made a mobile web application that looks good in all the different smart phones (iphone, windows, blackberry and android) under any orientation except the blackberry that has a small screen with a physical keyboard.   On this particular blackberry, the font size is too small.  What is a good way apply different styles or make fonts bigger on just these types of blackberries?

**Note** My app looks great on blackberries that have full screens with virtual keyboards.  It looks great in portrait and landscape.  So any solution I use to target the blackberries with small screens + physical keyboard must not interfere with the operation/cosmetics of the blackberries with full screens.

Comment: Is it a dedicated Blackberry app (Java), or a web app (Javascript) ?

Comment: it is a mobile website done in html 5 and css 3.

Comment: So you can't detect which device runs the application. You can detect weither it's a blackberry or not, but that's all. Everything is based on the User-Agent HTTP header, which doesn't contain such a "device-model" information.

Comment: Good idea.  I used PHP to output the contents of User-Agent HTTP and noticed it mentions the model of the blackberry being used.  Eg. it showed 'Blackberry 9700'.  SO maybe I just use regular expression to test for the names of all the blackberry models I know that have a small screen?

Comment: Does every device you target include such information in the User-Agent header ?

Comment: for all teh blackberries i've tested so far, it is telling me the model of the blackberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve your issue is to decide what physical criteria determines when you need to use a larger font and then test for that specific criteria.  It is best if you do NOT try to detect what type of device is hosting the page, but detect some characteristic of the device.

For example, you could decide that if the screen size is smaller than a x b, then you need to change the font size.   To do something like that, you could use a media query that was entirely CSS that set a different font size when certain screen size conditions where true.

I suspect that the issue is NOT that the device has a keyboard, but rather the constraints on the screen size that having a physical keyboard causes.  So, you should NOT focus on what type of device it is or whether it has a keyboard, but rather on what the screen dimensions are that cause you to need a different design.  Then, key your CSS/HTML or even javascript to detect that screen size and adapt accordingly.

If you decide that CSS media queries might be a useful approach, you will have to make sure that the target devices you most want this fix on support the particular CSS media queries you choose to use.

Here are some examples of how CSS media queries work:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Here's another SO post that talks about optimizing for display on Blackberries and testing:

[Blackberry media query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404617/blackberry-media-query)

Comment: This might sound dumb...but maybe you can help me understand.  Both the blackberry 9800 and 9700 have the screen resolution 480x360.  But the 9800 is full screen while 9700 is the small screen with physical keyboard.  So does that mean detecting solely screen resultion won't solve my problem?  (also, my understanding of screen res might be wrong, maybe there's another attribtue i should be looking at?)

Comment: @John - this is why I said you have to figure out which device characteristic actually distinguishes the situation you need to identify and do something different.  If both those screens are the same pixel count and you only want to do something different in one of them, then obviously you can't just use pixel count.  Perhaps you would want to use the `resolution` parameter and detect higher resolution screens where you want to use a larger font.  Or perhaps you want to just specify your fonts in pt instead of px so that your fonts are less dependent upon the resolution of the screen.